# Using Underscore functions inside Underscore templates webpack throws error undefined

Tags: javascript, templates, gulp, underscore.js, webpack

I'm trying to set up my project to use Gulp with Webpack as my bundler, I am using Underscore templates and in one of them I use `_.each()`. When I run webpack then reload I get an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined` which points to the template, can anyone advise how I expose underscore to the template?

**Webpack config**

```
    gulp.task('webpack', function() {
    return gulp.src('./app/scripts/index.js')
        .pipe(webpack({
            // watch: true,
            devtool: 'source-map',
            debug: true,
            output: {
                filename: 'bundle.js',
                path: __dirname
            },
            module: {
                loaders: [
                    {
                        test: /\.html$/,
                        loader: 'underscore-template-loader',
                        query: {
                            prependFilenameComment: __dirname,
                        },
                        exclude: /node_modules/,
                    },
                    { test: /imagesloaded/, loader: 'imports?define=>false&this=>window'},
                    { test: /underscore/, loader: 'exports?_' }
                    // { test: /backbone/, loader: 'exports?Backbone!imports?underscore,jquery' }
                ]
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/scripts'));
});
```

**Template**

```
<% _.each(movies, function(movie) { %>
    <a href="/movie/<%= movie.id %>" class="movie js-movie--show" data-id="<%= movie.id %>">
        <img src="<%= movie.backdrop_small %>" alt="" class="trans-img is-hidden js-trans-img">

        <span class="movie__info">
            <h2><%= movie.title %></h2>
        </span>
    </a>
<% }); %>
```

**My original Browserify bundler**

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {

    var exchange = {
        source_map: {
            file: 'bundle.js.map',
            root: '/',
            orig: ''
        }
    };

    var b = browserify({
        entries: './app/scripts/index.js',
        debug: true,
        transform: ['jstify']
    });

    return b.bundle()
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(extractor({
            removeSourcesContent: true
        }))
        .on('postextract', function(sourceMap) {
            exchange.source_map.orig = sourceMap;
        })
        .pipe(filter('**/*.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/scripts/'));
});
```

Comment: I see you use it, but i dont see you including it. Where do you link/`require()` `underscore.js` or `underscore.min.js`?

Comment: Turns out I need to make underscore globally available using webpack.ProvidePlugin